# delayed_job, keeping track of object's progress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progress-bar, delayed-job

I'm trying to get a progress bar going with `delayed job` but I don't know how check the status of the object.

I have an object called `Scrape` and it does some feed parsing or whatever so it takes about 30 seconds. What I cannot seem to do is find a way to access that object which has a progress integer attribute that keeps track of the parsing which I will call to make a simple %/css/div/ajax updater widget on the front side.

Can i use `object_id` since the object doesn't have an `id` until the process is complete/saved. If so how?

How an access this progress attribute on my object that is delayed. Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use some other datastore that is shared between the two processes, that is kept up to date. Maybe a memcached key?

The delayed_job process updates that key and the web app has an AJAX-based background poller which hits an endpoint which in turn queries the same key, returning a status update back to the client.

Comment: What do you mean some other datastore that is shared between the two processes. How can I do this, or where is an example of this?

Comment: Actually, this somehow pointed me in the right direction. Thanks :)